# Wordpress Contact Form 7 on Google App Engine

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, contact-form-7

Contact form 7 plugin doesn't work with Google App Engine Plugin. After submit form, I get a error `Failed to send your message. Contact the administrator...`

Other e-mail message are working, like **Forget password** or a **New user** message, but forms from Contact Form 7 doesn't work.

My settings:

[image: GAE]

And my contact form:

[image: contact form]

Somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

## Resolved!

The problem was: Google App Engine is needed that "From" be a Authorized on App Engine console. The solution is:

1. Open Google Cloud Console e go to App Engine > Settings > Application Settings > Email API authorized senders and add any e-mail
2. Go to WP Admin, App Engine settings and check option "Use App Engine Email Service" and add the email or "wordpress@appname.appspotmail.com"
3. On form mail settings, add "From" as "wordpress@appname.appspotmail.com". Don't forget clean "Reply-to"
4. Be happy!

Comment: Can you clarify what you did in step 2. Where can I find `App Engine Settings`?

Comment: There are two plugins one for Cloud Storage & One for App Engine [https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/wordpress-plugins](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/wordpress-plugins)